# Error IllegalStateException Cannot create a session after the response has been committed for large data set

Tags: java, wicket

I have a wicket application which works with some data. if the data is small everything works fine, if the data size changes to be very large, than it crashes with the following error:

```
Error IllegalStateException Cannot create a session after the response has been committed for large data set
```

I understand there is some buffer size which triggers automatic commit.

I am using Tomcat, where do I change this default size.

Comment: You need to create your session before starting pushing out the output.

Comment: This is someone else's code, but wouldn't it fail for small data as well. if when the session is created was the issue

Comment: No, because while the data fits into the buffer, it stays in the buffer. The cookie for the new session has to be sent out before any of the data (in the HTTP header), so if the buffer fills up and Wicket/Tomcat starts to write the data to the socket, there's no way to "rewind" and insert another header line. But if the data is small, writing only starts when all processing is finished.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't started writing anything to the response output stream, you can call [`ServletResponse.setBufferSize`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setBufferSize(int)) ... on a per-request basis.

There is no way to change Tomcat's default response buffer size.  It is hardwired into [the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.0/org/apache/catalina/connector/Response.java).  (Look for the place where `outputBuffer` is initialized, and what it is initialized to ...)